# Multiple Password DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I am creating an app that authenticates with users for AD, but then it also needs separate passwords to authenticate for two other services. Is there a way to use 3 passwords to verify login? I can set up log in verification individually for each service, but I was wondering if I could store all three passwords in the same session. Reason being is because users will need to authenticate with multiple services to use all functions of this app.

here is roughly what I am doing in my view.py

```
        request.session['pass_kinit2030'] = password
        request.session['reg_pass'] = reg_pass
        request.session['oraclepass'] = oraclepass
```

Comment: I don't think storing passwords in the session is a good idea (especially non-encrypted versions).

Comment: I'm guessing the communication to the other two services will be done using server-side (Python) not client-side (JS) so there's no need to authenticate using multiple passwords (just authenticate the user using the regular Django login and use the other passwords on behalf of the authenticated user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using multiple try/except methods to testing the logging in on the other other services.
try:

```
   try:
        a = add_user().login(username=creds['user'], password=creds['banpass'])
        add_user().logout(a)
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Banner Password Is Incorrect')
        return redirect('login')
    if Usermanager(creds=creds).test_login():
        pass
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Wrong Regular Account Credentials')
        return redirect('login')
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect('userinfo')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Wrong AdminCredentials')
        return redirect('login')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see several options:

1. If all your 3 passwords are equal, I suppose you just define your own [`AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) in Django. In such backend you would just take the password and check if it's valid in all three services.

In `yourapp/auth.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend

class MyAuthBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        # Check reg and oracle - if valid, return request.user, else return None
```

In `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['yourapp.auth.MyAuthBackend']
```

But since you said `separate passwords`, I suppose they are not equal.

2. In case passwords are not equal, it is questionable to ask for 2 other passwords in this single app, in the first place. You shouldn't ask the user for 2 other passwords in the login form. Normally, you should authenticate your other two apps using some kind of token. You then connect your apps with such token in a different view than login view. Having such token, you should keep its value in a new model that has `OneToOneField` relationship to the user:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class UserTokens(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reg_token = forms.CharField(
        null=True,
        max_length=100)
    oracle_token = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        max_length=100)
```

You might as well use a password as a token, as long as the password is generated in a similar way to a token (and cannot be changed to a value given by the user - I know such cases).

3. Last but not least, you may not like the idea of tokens or may not have them implemented in related two apps. Then the question is, how these two apps are accessed? Are they HTTP servers? If yes, you are all set. The browser should keep the login session to two other apps separately. And, still you can redirect to these apps / iframe them or do JavaScript GETs or POSTs, if we talk about API of some kind - yes JS requests will use the login session.